# constexpr C++ error: destructor used before its definition

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

I'm experiencing an error using g++-12 which does not occur in clang++-13.  In particular, this code:

```
struct A {
    constexpr virtual ~A() = default;
    constexpr A() = default;
};

struct B : public A {
    constexpr ~B() = default;
    constexpr B() = default;
};

constexpr int demo(){
    B *b = new B();
    delete b;
    return 2;
}

int main(){
    constexpr int demod = demo();
    return demod;
}
```

Compiles with clang++, but with g++ gives the error:

```text
minimize-error.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
minimize-error.cpp:18:31:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘demo()’
minimize-error.cpp:13:12: error: ‘virtual constexpr B::~B()’ used before its definition
   13 |     delete b;
      |
```

Curiously, if I just remove the `constexpr` requirement on `demod`, the example compiles and runs without error.

Any ideas as to what's happening here?

Comment: I think it's this known bug menifesting https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93413

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a GCC bug, see [this report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93413).

Virtual defaulted destructors don't seem to work at all in constant evaluation with current GCC. As also mentioned in the bug report, simply

```
struct A{
    constexpr virtual ~A() = default;
};

constexpr A a;
```

also fails.

As a workaround you can provide definitions for the destructors manually instead of defaulting:

```
constexpr virtual ~A() {}

/*...*/

constexpr ~B() {}
```

Then GCC seems happy.

Answer (score 10):

As it turns out, there's a workaround to make Virtual defaulted destructors work in constant evaluation with current GCC! As [StoryTeller indicated in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72835571/constexpr-c-errorr-destructor-used-before-its-definition#comment128648489_72835571), this is an instance of bug [93413](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93413).  The duplicate bug [104653](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104653) suggests a workaround:

```
struct A{
    constexpr virtual ~A() = default;
    constexpr A() = default;
};

struct B : public A {
    virtual constexpr ~B() override;
    constexpr B() = default;
};

constexpr B::~B() = default;

consteval int demo(){
    B *b = new B();
    delete b;
    return 2;
}

int main(){
    return demo();
}
```